# Regression Line and Color not been added to a scatterplot (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am running a regression of the share of GDP in Agriculture on total GDP per capita. The regression command worked and I obtained the desired coefficient.

However, I aim to create a scatterplot for it by adding country code and labels and color for the country Somalia represented by the code "SOM". I keep on running into the following error:

```
geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
Warning messages:
1: Removed 7 rows containing non-finite values (stat_smooth). 
2: Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`:
'what' must be a function or character string 
3: Removed 7 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

The codes that I have tried:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = log(gdp_pc_ppp), y = agri_gdp_sh), label = CountryCode) + geom_point(data = subset(scatterplot_2015, CountryCode=="SOM")) + geom_smooth(method = reg1, se=FALSE) 

ggplot(df, aes(x = log(gdp_pc_ppp), y = agri_gdp_sh), color = CountryCode) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = reg1, se=FALSE)
```

Sample of the data set:

```
structure(list(agri_gdp_sh = structure(c(0.12762394336879, 0.206343227166798, 
0.205901057158598, 0.0912253447070414), label = "Agriculture, forestry, and fishing, value added (% of GDP) [NV.AGR.TOTL.ZS]", format.stata = "%10.0g"), 
    gdp_pc_ppp = structure(c(3726.70123167662, 2068.26590413364, 
    4216.40920637826, 8036.41089824639), label = "GDP per capita, PPP (constant 2017 international $) [NY.GDP.PCAP.PP.KD]", format.stata = "%10.0g"), 
    CountryCode = structure(3:6, .Label = c("", "ABW", "AFE", 
    "AFG", "AFW", "AGO", "ALB", "AND", "ARB", "ARE", "ARG", "ARM", 
    "ASM", "ATG", "AUS", "AUT", "AZE", "BDI", "BEL", "BEN", "BFA", 
    "BGD", "BGR", "BHR", "BHS", "BIH", "BLR", "BLZ", "BMU", "BOL", 
    "BRA", "BRB", "BRN", "BTN", "BWA", "CAF", "CAN", "CEB", "CHE", 
    "CHI", "CHL", "CHN", "CIV", "CMR", "COD", "COG", "COL", "COM", 
    "CPV", "CRI", "CSS", "CUB", "CUW", "CYM", "CYP", "CZE", "DEU", 
    "DJI", "DMA", "DNK", "DOM", "DZA", "EAP", "EAR", "EAS", "ECA", 
    "ECS", "ECU", "EGY", "EMU", "ERI", "ESP", "EST", "ETH", "EUU", 
    "FCS", "FIN", "FJI", "FRA", "FRO", "FSM", "GAB", "GBR", "GEO", 
    "GHA", "GIB", "GIN", "GMB", "GNB", "GNQ", "GRC", "GRD", "GRL", 
    "GTM", "GUM", "GUY", "HIC", "HKG", "HND", "HPC", "HRV", "HTI", 
    "HUN", "IBD", "IBT", "IDA", "IDB", "IDN", "IDX", "IMN", "IND", 
    "INX", "IRL", "IRN", "IRQ", "ISL", "ISR", "ITA", "JAM", "JOR", 
    "JPN", "KAZ", "KEN", "KGZ", "KHM", "KIR", "KNA", "KOR", "KWT", 
    "LAC", "LAO", "LBN", "LBR", "LBY", "LCA", "LCN", "LDC", "LIC", 
    "LIE", "LKA", "LMC", "LMY", "LSO", "LTE", "LTU", "LUX", "LVA", 
    "MAC", "MAF", "MAR", "MCO", "MDA", "MDG", "MDV", "MEA", "MEX", 
    "MHL", "MIC", "MKD", "MLI", "MLT", "MMR", "MNA", "MNE", "MNG", 
    "MNP", "MOZ", "MRT", "MUS", "MWI", "MYS", "NAC", "NAM", "NCL", 
    "NER", "NGA", "NIC", "NLD", "NOR", "NPL", "NRU", "NZL", "OED", 
    "OMN", "OSS", "PAK", "PAN", "PER", "PHL", "PLW", "PNG", "POL", 
    "PRE", "PRI", "PRK", "PRT", "PRY", "PSE", "PSS", "PST", "PYF", 
    "QAT", "ROU", "RUS", "RWA", "SAS", "SAU", "SDN", "SEN", "SGP", 
    "SLB", "SLE", "SLV", "SMR", "SOM", "SRB", "SSA", "SSD", "SSF", 
    "SST", "STP", "SUR", "SVK", "SVN", "SWE", "SWZ", "SXM", "SYC", 
    "SYR", "TCA", "TCD", "TEA", "TEC", "TGO", "THA", "TJK", "TKM", 
    "TLA", "TLS", "TMN", "TON", "TSA", "TSS", "TTO", "TUN", "TUR", 
    "TUV", "TZA", "UGA", "UKR", "UMC", "URY", "USA", "UZB", "VCT", 
    "VEN", "VGB", "VIR", "VNM", "VUT", "WLD", "WSM", "XKX", "YEM", 
    "ZAF", "ZMB", "ZWE"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: First, you need to specify a correct "method" in `geom_smooth`: check the help file, my guess is that either `lm` should work fine, or that you need something else entirely, but for that we need to know what's in `reg1`. Second, to apply color to your  points, specify the color aesthetic inside `geom_point`: `geom_point(aes(color = CountryCode))`.

Comment: Hi, it worked out. However, is there a way to add color for only a particular country? There are 153 countries and colors are not making any sense.

Comment: You could use an `ifelse` statement: `geom_point(aes(color = ifelse(CountryCode == "SOM", "SOM", "Other country"))`? Or add a column to your data-set that would contain this information and use it to define your aesthetic parameter.